# How to remap Enter key in vim?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim, iterm2, kinesis-advantage

I just got a Kinesis Advantage keyboard and want to remap Enter to Esc in insert mode in vim. I'm using iTerm2 as well.

Here's what I've got so far:

`inoremap <CR> <Esc>
inoremap jj <Esc>
nnoremap <CR> i`

On startup, this does not work: Enter enters insert mode, and in insert mode, `jj` exits insert mode. However, Enter does not exit from insert mode.

Then I reload my vimrc file:

`:so $MYVIMRC`

And viola, my Enter key now exits insert mode and everything works fine.

Any thoughts on why this would be happening?

Thanks

Comment: It is likely you have something overriding the mapping. What does "`:verbose imap <cr>`" show?

Comment: Aha, that's exactly what's happening. Before reloading, it reads: `i  <CR>        * pumvisible() ? "\<C-N>" : "\<CR>"
        Last set from ~/vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/youcompleteme.vim`, and after: `i  <CR>        * <Esc>
        Last set from ~/.vimrc`. Thank you! Want to make an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when you have a plugin or other script sourced after your mapping is defined that overrides your mapping.  The easiest way to find out which is to run this command:

```
:verbose imap <cr>
```

This will tell you what the key sequence is mapped to, and what script defined the mapping.